# ReactJs - SyntaxError: embedded: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and I have a stupid issue, I think, but I can't see a reason's place of it.
My training code:

```
var ListComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.value}</li>
        );
    }
});

var TodoComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            listPoints: []
        }
    },
    addListPoint: function(event) {
        if (event.target.value !== '') {
            this.setState({
                listPoints: this.state.listPoints.push(event.target.value)
            });
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        var listPoints = [];
        for (var i=0; i<this.state.listPoints.length; i++) {
            listPoints.push(
                <ListComponent>{this.state.listPoints[i]}<ListComponent/>
            );
        }
        return (
            <ul>{listPoints}</ul>
            <input type="text" onBlur={this.addListPoint}/>
        );
    },
});


React.render(
    <TodoComponent />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And my traceback:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unterminated JSX contents (42:21)
  40 |  
  41 | React.render(
> 42 |     <TodoComponent />,
     |                      ^
  43 |     document.getElementById('container')
  44 | );
  45 |
```

Every tag seems to be closed. Does someone point me to a place where the issue begun?

Comment: How are you transforming the JSX into JS?  Webpack + babel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not closing your list properly:

```
<ListComponent>{this.state.listPoints[i]}</ListComponent>
```

You wrote `<ListComponent/>` (a self-closing tag with no content)

Also you need to do what Kohei TAKATA says - render should have one root element (though in React 16+ you can return an array or wrap your elements in `<React.Fragment>`).

Comment: error in the component also show as the error in the React.render() function...isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Your `render` function of `TodoComponent` returns 2 elements.
I think it must be one element.
Please try to enclose the 2 elements by `<div>` or something.
Like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>{listPoints}</ul>
    <input type="text" onBlur={this.addListPoint}/>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe but it was still one of the problem in your code nonetheless. A component must embed everything in an enclosing tag.

Comment: Yes. Now I see it. Thank you for that also.